# A question about Integral on a bounded function

Tags: integration

Is this statement correct:

> Let $F$ be a positive upper bounded function then for sufficiently small $\epsilon$ the function $F^\epsilon$ is bounded

Comment: Is "$F^{\varepsilon}$" $F$ to the power $\varepsilon$ ?

Comment: yes exactly, $F^ε$, i.e, $F$ to the power $ε$

Answer (score 1):

If F is positive and upper bounded, then F is obviously bounded. Hence the statement holds for $\epsilon=1$ (and for other finite $\epsilon$ as well).

Comment: This is not the answer of my question